# JSON with jq into bash array / loop through for proper alerting output

Tags: bash, docker, shell, jq

I have a JSON result which I want to go through and send an alert, if one or several of the values in the JSON string is smashing thresholds.

This bash command:

```sh
for sat in `docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r`; do docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/$sat | jq .id,.audits; done
```

Provides the following (excerpt):

```JSON
"12tRQrMTWUWwzwGh18i7Fqs67kmdhH9t6aToeiwbo5mfS2rUmo"
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "onlineScore": 0.9974358974358974,
  "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
}
"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE"
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "onlineScore": 0.9989041005632043,
  "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
}
```

Now I want to go through the results and e.g. in case, onlineScore drops below 0.9 (or suspensionScore resp. auditScore below 1.0, I want to create a text alert, which also includes the satelliteName. Example: `auditScore below threshold: 0.98 for us2.storj.io`

I guess I can start with the following (from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq), but I do not know, how to loop through the results and how to name and validate the fields:

```sh
jq -r '.[] | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)'
```

What the above mentioned statement delivers in subtleties:

```sh
docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno
```

provides:

```json
{"nodeID":"1veqEG5xuBNkt...","wallet":"12345","walletFeatures":["zksync"],"satellites":[{"id":"12tRQrMTWUWwzwGh18i7Fqs67kmdhH9t6aToeiwbo5mfS2rUmo","url":"us2.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":4592556672},{"id":"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE","url":"saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":513269323264},{"id":"121RTSDpyNZVcEU84Ticf2L1ntiuUimbWgfATz21tuvgk3vzoA6","url":"ap1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":70956116864},{"id":"12EayRS2V1kEsWESU9QMRseFhdxYxKicsiFmxrsLZHeLUtdps3S","url":"us1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":322340591104},{"id":"12L9ZFwhzVpuEKMUNUqkaTLGzwY9G24tbiigLiXpmZWKwmcNDDs","url":"eu1.storj.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":148740125312},{"id":"12rfG3sh9NCWiX3ivPjq2HtdLmbqCrvHVEzJubnzFzosMuawymB","url":"europe-north-1.tardigrade.io:7777","disqualified":null,"suspended":null,"currentStorageUsed":100681406976}],"diskSpace":{"used":1162257094528,"available":9500000000000,"trash":43196690332,"overused":0},"bandwidth":{"used":31670206976,"available":0},"lastPinged":"2022-01-02T07:55:51.886776586Z","version":"1.45.3","allowedVersion":"1.24.0","upToDate":true,"startedAt":"2021-12-31T00:00:32.209840775Z"}
```

And this one:

```sh
docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE
```

provides:

```json
{"id":"1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE","storageDaily":[{"atRestTotal":11726579066524.266,"intervalStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"}],"bandwidthDaily":[{"egress":{"repair":390576640,"audit":7424,"usage":2373615872},"ingress":{"repair":2745100032,"usage":26744320},"delete":0,"intervalStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"egress":{"repair":143168256,"audit":3584,"usage":786989568},"ingress":{"repair":1034401280,"usage":8107264},"delete":0,"intervalStart":"2022-01-02T00:00:00Z"}],"storageSummary":11726579066524.266,"bandwidthSummary":7508714240,"egressSummary":3694361344,"ingressSummary":3814352896,"currentStorageUsed":513269323264,"audits":{"auditScore":1,"suspensionScore":1,"onlineScore":0.9989041005632043,"satelliteName":"saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"},"auditHistory":{"score":0.9989041005632043,"windows":[{"windowStart":"2021-12-03T00:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-03T12:00:00Z","totalCount":30,"onlineCount":30},{"windowStart":"2021-12-04T00:00:00Z","totalCount":43,"onlineCount":42},{"windowStart":"2021-12-04T12:00:00Z","totalCount":68,"onlineCount":68},{"windowStart":"2021-12-05T00:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-05T12:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-06T00:00:00Z","totalCount":33,"onlineCount":33},{"windowStart":"2021-12-06T12:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-07T00:00:00Z","totalCount":27,"onlineCount":27},{"windowStart":"2021-12-07T12:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-08T00:00:00Z","totalCount":30,"onlineCount":30},{"windowStart":"2021-12-08T12:00:00Z","totalCount":27,"onlineCount":27},{"windowStart":"2021-12-09T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46},{"windowStart":"2021-12-09T12:00:00Z","totalCount":48,"onlineCount":48},{"windowStart":"2021-12-10T00:00:00Z","totalCount":49,"onlineCount":49},{"windowStart":"2021-12-10T12:00:00Z","totalCount":67,"onlineCount":67},{"windowStart":"2021-12-11T00:00:00Z","totalCount":71,"onlineCount":71},{"windowStart":"2021-12-11T12:00:00Z","totalCount":52,"onlineCount":52},{"windowStart":"2021-12-12T00:00:00Z","totalCount":59,"onlineCount":59},{"windowStart":"2021-12-12T12:00:00Z","totalCount":77,"onlineCount":77},{"windowStart":"2021-12-13T00:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-13T12:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-14T00:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-14T12:00:00Z","totalCount":59,"onlineCount":59},{"windowStart":"2021-12-15T00:00:00Z","totalCount":87,"onlineCount":87},{"windowStart":"2021-12-15T12:00:00Z","totalCount":82,"onlineCount":81},{"windowStart":"2021-12-16T00:00:00Z","totalCount":96,"onlineCount":96},{"windowStart":"2021-12-16T12:00:00Z","totalCount":66,"onlineCount":64},{"windowStart":"2021-12-17T00:00:00Z","totalCount":36,"onlineCount":36},{"windowStart":"2021-12-17T12:00:00Z","totalCount":48,"onlineCount":48},{"windowStart":"2021-12-18T00:00:00Z","totalCount":37,"onlineCount":37},{"windowStart":"2021-12-18T12:00:00Z","totalCount":60,"onlineCount":60},{"windowStart":"2021-12-19T00:00:00Z","totalCount":69,"onlineCount":69},{"windowStart":"2021-12-19T12:00:00Z","totalCount":32,"onlineCount":32},{"windowStart":"2021-12-20T00:00:00Z","totalCount":53,"onlineCount":53},{"windowStart":"2021-12-20T12:00:00Z","totalCount":37,"onlineCount":37},{"windowStart":"2021-12-21T00:00:00Z","totalCount":80,"onlineCount":80},{"windowStart":"2021-12-21T12:00:00Z","totalCount":57,"onlineCount":57},{"windowStart":"2021-12-22T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46},{"windowStart":"2021-12-22T12:00:00Z","totalCount":33,"onlineCount":33},{"windowStart":"2021-12-23T00:00:00Z","totalCount":42,"onlineCount":42},{"windowStart":"2021-12-23T12:00:00Z","totalCount":73,"onlineCount":73},{"windowStart":"2021-12-24T00:00:00Z","totalCount":35,"onlineCount":35},{"windowStart":"2021-12-24T12:00:00Z","totalCount":44,"onlineCount":44},{"windowStart":"2021-12-25T00:00:00Z","totalCount":81,"onlineCount":81},{"windowStart":"2021-12-25T12:00:00Z","totalCount":43,"onlineCount":43},{"windowStart":"2021-12-26T00:00:00Z","totalCount":62,"onlineCount":62},{"windowStart":"2021-12-26T12:00:00Z","totalCount":79,"onlineCount":79},{"windowStart":"2021-12-27T00:00:00Z","totalCount":70,"onlineCount":70},{"windowStart":"2021-12-27T12:00:00Z","totalCount":90,"onlineCount":90},{"windowStart":"2021-12-28T00:00:00Z","totalCount":65,"onlineCount":65},{"windowStart":"2021-12-28T12:00:00Z","totalCount":77,"onlineCount":77},{"windowStart":"2021-12-29T00:00:00Z","totalCount":83,"onlineCount":83},{"windowStart":"2021-12-29T12:00:00Z","totalCount":99,"onlineCount":99},{"windowStart":"2021-12-30T00:00:00Z","totalCount":74,"onlineCount":74},{"windowStart":"2021-12-30T12:00:00Z","totalCount":84,"onlineCount":84},{"windowStart":"2021-12-31T00:00:00Z","totalCount":70,"onlineCount":70},{"windowStart":"2021-12-31T12:00:00Z","totalCount":93,"onlineCount":93},{"windowStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z","totalCount":120,"onlineCount":120},{"windowStart":"2022-01-01T12:00:00Z","totalCount":112,"onlineCount":112},{"windowStart":"2022-01-02T00:00:00Z","totalCount":46,"onlineCount":46}]},"priceModel":{"EgressBandwidth":2000,"RepairBandwidth":1000,"AuditBandwidth":1000,"DiskSpace":150},"nodeJoinedAt":"2021-05-11T20:11:14.910165Z"}
```

Sorry, not sure how to better format the huge json content here in a better way.

Thank you for your help. I am not sure how I can modify the output, loop through the results and create the corresponding target output. jq as a tool is new for me and the documentation is not yet self-explanatory for me.

**UPDATE #1**

There is a result for `http://localhost:14002/api/sno/satellites`, I was not aware of before. The result is:

```json
{
...
   "storageSummary": 6.8624392E13,
...
   "audits": [
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
         "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
      },
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
         "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
      },
...
      {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
         "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
      }
   ]
}
```

I think that makes the required handling much easier at the end, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add threshold variables and values using `--argjson` (preferred over `--arg` as we talk about numbers), then extract from the `.audits` object each item that smashes the corresponding threshold using `select`, format them in a way to carry the actual value and the threshold to be reused in the output, and finally convert those items into an alert string (which will be output as is due to the `--raw-output` parameter).

```sh
for sat in `docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r`
do
  docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/$sat \
  | jq --raw-output \
    --argjson auditThreshold 1 \
    --argjson suspensionThreshold 1 \
    --argjson onlineThreshold 1 \
    '.audits
      | .satelliteName as $name
      | (
          [{auditScore}, $auditThreshold],
          [{suspensionScore}, $suspensionThreshold],
          [{onlineScore}, $onlineThreshold]
        )
      | select(.[0][] < .[1])
      | "\(.[0] | keys[]) (\(.[0][])) below threshold (\(.[1])) for \($name)"
    '
done
```

```
onlineScore (0.9989041005632043) below threshold (1) for saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777
```

[Simplified Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xvDgRDMjno)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Can you please propose / add 1-2 lines in order to store the output into a single variable (let‘s name it audit_msg)? I would expect to have it empty, in case there is no score below the thresholds and with content, in case there is any broken threshold.

Comment: To store the output of a bash command into a bash variable use `x="$(for … done)"` onto the whole expression (Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)). However, with this script you'd just store lines of text (like the contents of a logfile, if you will). Depending on what you want the stored output for, I'd probably rather go with storing a (reduced and filtered but not yet stringified) JSON that you can then query using `jq` if you need any part of its content, eg. `jq '.[].auditScore | …' <<< "$x"` or the like.

Comment: Pretty cool. I‘ll take that and probably modify it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've found out, that there is a url call, which directly collects all the required data - without the need to loop separate docker commands or curl requests: `http://localhost:14002/api/sno/satellites` can be used instead. I'll add it as an update #1 in the original post (due to chars limitation in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

You can produce an output which can readable to a while read loop (i.e. `while read audit_score suspension_score online_score satellite_name; do`) by changing `jq .id,.audits` to `jq -r '.audits | "\(.auditScore) \(.suspensionScore) \(.onlineScore) \(.satelliteName)"'`.  Use `bc` as a comparison tool since Bash doesn't support floating points.

Also this took me a while to compose but you can compose the messages directly using this:

```
jq -r '.audits | 
    (select(.auditScore < 1) | "auditScore below threshold: \(.auditScore) for \(.satelliteName)"),
    (select(.suspensionScore < 1) | "suspensionScore below threshold: \(.suspensionScore) for \(.satelliteName)"),
    (select(.onlineScore < 1) | "onlineScore below threshold: \(.onlineScore) for \(.satelliteName)")
'
```

It should work even with merged outputs from this:

```
docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - localhost:14002/api/sno | jq .satellites[].id -r | \
    xargs -I'{}' docker exec -i storagenode wget -qO - 'localhost:14002/api/sno/satellite/{}'
```

Comment: Very interesting and helpful. Thank you! I‘ll try with the other proposal, but maybe come back to yours. You might want and be able to help with my question in the comment below? :)